# How to restrict the number to fixed length if the field is number type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, numbers, ruby-on-rails-5

Here is the code

```
<%= form.number_field :marks,label: "CGPA*", maxlength:"4"  %>
```

[image: Percentage and CGPA number fields filled with long numbers]

In this code, the form is a number field. How can I restrict its length?
As shown in this picture it's taking more than 4 characters.

Comment: <%= form.number_field :marks,label: "CGPA*", step: 1,  min: 1, max:4 %>

Comment: ya i tried this but its taking more than 4 characters

Comment: So you should use java script for the same

Comment: "ya i tried this but its taking more than 4 characters" - is the submit which is blocked, it won't block people from introducing higher values @SaiCharanReddyReddy